# Artificial intelligence in Hindu texts

Tags: scripture, science

Hindu texts contain instances about [space-time relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakudmi#Meeting_with_Brahma), [space vehicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salwa_Kingdom#Salwa_king_contemporary_to_Krishna) and many others.

In present day world, the rising of Artificial Intelligence is phenomenal. It will become major part of human life in future. In some areas it is performing better than humans [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Blue_(chess_computer)#Deep_Blue_versus_Kasparov), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlphaGo_versus_Lee_Sedol).

Is there any mention of such intelligent machines in Hindu ancient texts (For example: Pushpaka Vimana, Saubha Vimana etc.,)  or any indication/ prediction about such intelligent systems in Kaliyuga?

In concise, Are there any slokas supporting or condemning the generation of intelligence by non-living systems?

Comment: You've come to the right place if you have questions about:
Hindu scripture and mythology. 


How this question does not come under the Hindu scripture and mythology?

Comment: How this question comes under scientific speculation? I did not ask for any scientific proof or reason, I just asked about mention about artificial intelligence / intelligent systems in Hindu texts.

Comment: Pushpaka Vimana, Saubha Vimana are mentioned in Hindu texts, Like wise I  asked for reference only, not the science behind developing AI machines.

Comment: "what can be achieved in 100 years in Krita Yuga, takes 10 years in Treta Yuga, takes 1 year in Dvarpara Yuga, and 1 day in Kali Yuga" - this is in our scriptures. You can clearly see it happening now.. If you wanted to travel from India to USA, it would take months before.. after trains, ships, buses were invented, a few weeks, but after planes, it takes one day. If you wanted to learn about computers, it would take a university education before, but after Google, it takes only a few clicks. That is the advent of Kali

Comment: @ram But satya yuga is 4 times of kali yuga, treta yuga is 3 times of kaliyuga and dwapara yuga is 2 times of kali yuga.

Comment: yeah, but the duration of yuga is linear scale, whereas duration of effort needed is logarithmic scale

Comment: I heard there are references to androids in some texts but unfortunately it's very hazy to me where it is right now.

Comment: In books and biography of great king bhoja